# applicationWillResignActive called without reason on iOS 10 ( swift 3 )

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

When I launch my app on iOS 10, I can see that after a short delay, the Appdelegate   function -> applicationWillResignActive() is called.
There is no reason for that. The app is still active and in foreground state when it occurs and the app continues to run normally.

Please see above the lifecycle of my app :

--> Click on the app icon

- App launch
- application            -->  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
- application            -->  applicationDidBecomeActive
- RootViewController     -->  viewDidAppear
- application            -->  applicationWillResignActive  <-- issue !
- application            -->  applicationDidBecomeActive  <-- again ??!!
- at this point, the app is still running with no error

This sequence is repeated each time I open the app.

It looks as if something forces my app to quit the foreground state for an ultra short delay.
Usually, applicationDidBecomeActive is called when the app displays an alert ( for example if the app requires an user's permission to access the camera ) or when the user clicks on the home button.

1 - It only occurs when the app starts in landscape mode
 2 - It only occurs on iPhones and not on iPads
 3 - The problem does NOT occur on an iOS 9 device

Did anyone noticed this problem ?

Comment: I do not experience this issue,  anyway you can create a test project

Comment: I think it's a bug in iOS 10, I opened a bug report.

Comment: if only you can experience this bug, then it is you, not iOS 10

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive

Comment: @Knight0fDragon  :  If you had read Apple's documentation above, you would have learned that this function is only called when the application ''begins the transition to the background state'' or receives ''temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message)''.
In my case, I can confirm that the app stays in foreground and no interruption of any kind is received.
Second, it is well known that Apple never made a bug... The ''AppleBug Reporter'' is filled by bad devs who believe that their bugs are Apple bugs...

Comment: Apparently you are not understanding,  I cannot recreate your bug, I do not experience this issue, that is why I am asking if you could create a test project, because right now it is only you that sees this happening.  Provide a test case and we can determine if it is apple or if it is you

Comment: "Apple never made a bug" hahahahahahahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, it calls second time after dismissing system services alert (location, push notifications, photos)

So the only way to handle it is to use variable in AppDelegate which increments each time some system alert shows and decrements in `applicationDidBecomeActive`, so you call your code only if value of this variable is 1.

Another interesting thing is that `applicationDidEnterBackground` doesn't call when system alert shows, thus we can use this info to decide whether we should call our code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` or not (but still, it can be less reliable solution)

Comment: You are absolutely right ! If you have an system event listener, I would be very interested ! Thanks.

Comment: I fixed my problem by checking the orientation of the device because waiting for applicationDidEnterBackground is too late in the lifecycle of the app. The data that I need to save won't save.

Comment: There is a notification called `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification` that gets called before didEnterBackground,  add a listener to that, You should be able to save in this stage

Comment: I tried to add a listener but xcode says UIApplicationSuspendedNotification is not a valid notification name. I did not found the documentation of this notification. May be it's deprecated in UIKit 3.